# While loop in Python using Lambda

Tags: python

Here is my simple demo while loop.

```
count = 0
while count < 5:
   print 'The count is:', count
   count = count + 1
```

Now i want to change the normal while loop using lambdas.

```
def func():
    count = 0
    print 'The count is:', count
    count += 1

a = lambda count: (count < 5 and func() )
print a
```

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: What happens and what do you expect?

Comment: "What i am doing wrong ?" Everything. Lambdas don't work like that. And I don't see how what you have done is "putting a while loop in lambda" or whatever you were trying to do. Please explain yourself.

Comment: I am trying to implement while loop using lambdas .

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code has many things wrong, and I don't think  `lambda` should be used for calling another function without return value. If you have to do it, it would be like:

```
def func(n):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        print 'The count is:', i
        i += 1

a = lambda count: func(count)
a(5)
```

Comment: Y is it prints None 5 times in the bottom. I think we should return things inside function but that produces a list.

Comment: return what **things**?

Comment: @user3012137 try again.

Comment: Ok I got it, but None should not print right .

Comment: @user3012137 it doesn't print `None` now.

Comment: Downvoter: explain why you downvoted this answer ?

Comment: @user3012137 I didn't downvote this, but probably because abusing a list comprehension for looping isn't exactly pythonic or generally a good idea.

Comment: @Skyler All functions have a return value

Answer (score 2):

a lambda has nothing to do with loop. It's just some inline way to define a function.

Instead of using a lambda you could have written the code below. The mere difference with using a lambda is that the function defined get a name.

```
def func(n):
    print 'The count is:', n

def mylambda(count): 
    return (count < 5 and func())

a = mylambda

print a
```

Now may be you can see by yourself what's wrong ?

- just writing 'a' does not call the function (parenthesis needed)
- your lambda need a parameter for count
- there is no loop, you are just computing a boolean combining the predicate 'count < 5' and the result of calling func()
- func returns nothing, henceforth it will always return None
- you get a function that will return either False or None depending of the value of the parameter count...

Actually, I'm still wondering what you were trying to do ? Call a lambda in a loop ? Create a recursive lambda ? Anyone's guess until more details.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem lies in the fine print

[See section Function definitions for the syntax of parameter lists. Note that functions created with lambda expressions cannot contain statements.](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

and `while` is part of [Compund Statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html)

To Simplify,

If you can write your function in the form

```
def name(arguments):
    return expression
```

You can convert it to lambda as

```
name = lambda arguments: expression
```

> I am trying to implement while loop using lambdas

You should seriously consider using [itertools.dropwhile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) or [itertools.takewhile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)

Comment: Yes, i know that. i am just playing with lambdas.

Comment: @user3012137: Feel free to play, but handle with care. Read the literature carefully before using :-)

Answer (score -2):

You are not even calling your lambda function:

```
def func(n):
    print 'The count is:', n

# funcParam will be a function
a = lambda funcParam, count: (funcParam(i) for i in range(count))
a(func, 5)
```

Comment: this one returns generator expression (ge) and do not calls func even once unitl ge is exhausted.